# best MySql administrator program for performing administrative operations?

Tags: mysql, administrative

what's the best MySql administrator program (free) for performing administrative operations, such as configuring MySQL server, monitoring its status and performance, starting and stopping it and...?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).  It is free, and does what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Heidi](http://www.heidisql.com/), like it very much.